# Visual Studio debugger crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

So I'm having some weird error in visual studio. The debugger crashes (I think). Here is the function where it crashes. This is for a generic BST in C#, where the == operator was overloaded to add easy comparison between nodes.

```
    public static bool operator ==(Node<T> lhs, Node<T> rhs)
    {
        if ((lhs == null) || (rhs == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if((lhs.Data).CompareTo(rhs.Data) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It crashes at this line:

```
if ((lhs == null) || (rhs == null))
```

Upon debugging, lhs is indeed null, as soon as it starts comparing, it hangs up, then displays this message:

[image]

Then the debugging session just ends itself.

I don't really understand because in order to try to find out the problem with my code, I'm attempting to debug, but then this error happens and the session just ends itself. I've never seen this before.

Comment: Try `if (lhs.Equals(null) || rhs.Equals(null))`, I think you are kicking off some infinite recursion.

Comment: Stackoverflow. Use `ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || ReferenceEquals(rhs, null)` otherwise you are invoking the == operator recursively.

Comment: @RonBeyer that will throw a null reference exception if either is null

Comment: *In my overload of `operator ==`, the first thing I do is use `==`*. What do you think will happen here?

Comment: @KenWhite I guess the reason it confused me is becuase the two types I used in my overloaded operator were Node<T> and Node<T>, I didn't really consider null a Node<T>, so I didn't think it would recursively call the overloaded operator. I figured it would maybe use the default == for the comparison.

I ended up including a reference equals comparison, then checking if either was null, then finally comparing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the `==` operator recursively. Use `if (ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))` to avoid this.

Alternatively, with C#7 pattern matching:
`if (lhs is null || rhs is null)`

Comment: Yes this worked. Also visual studio recommended that I simplify your answer by usuing "lhs is null" and "rhs is null". I think it's the exact same thing, just a little cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: That's c#7 syntax, but yeah it will work. This answer will work for all versions of c#.

Comment: Upon further expection, as a result of the recursive error, it was causing a stack overflow exception.